# Build Mac App IPA without Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, ipa

I'm simply trying to upload my .app to the Mac App store. I've paid my developer fees, set up **all** of my certificates, devices, and profiles (what a load of ****), and installed Application Loader 3.0.

I'm being prompted to import an IPA file. However my .app is a packaged Java application (with JRE bundled). So it was not generated with Xcode.
The app is signed and entitlements are attached.

I've been through the documentation, however, every guide I come across goes on to talk about exporting the IPA file with Xcode. I didn't use Xcode!

This whole procedure has been a real mess.

So, is there any way I can generate an IPA file without Xcode?

Thank you.

Comment: Helps if you read about the process before hand. Just because you built a java app that runs on os x does not mean you built a Java app that is ready for Mac App Store distribution

Comment: An ipa is just a zip archive. But there are more hurdles than *creating* the ipa. You'll need to get the entitlements right, code signing and whatever else. That's probably not even possible with a java executable.

Comment: I'm not sure what else I'm missing... I'm assuming I need to sign my app and generate an IPA. Can I do this from the command line? Most of Apple's documentation on the topic assumes you're using Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I after much tinkering, I found out I could create a PKG file instead.

So in the same directory as "YourApp.app":

1. Create entitlement file (`ent.entitlements`)
2. Sign files:

   `codesign -v -f -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Your Name" --entitlements ent.entitlements YourApp.app`

   `find YourApp.app/Contents/ -type f \( -name "*.jar" -or -name "*.dylib" -or -name "jspawnhelper" \) -exec codesign --verbose -f -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Your Name" --entitlements ent.entitlements {} \;`
3. Build package:

   `productbuild --component "YourApp.app" /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Your Name" YourApp.pkg`

Then I could open the package in Application Loader.

A good resource:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/secure/attachment/15809/MacAppSandboxTestingNotes.txt